# From Google Sheets | HTTP Request API to pass edited cell past and new value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to call an HTTP API from google sheets ,

```
function atEdit(eventObj) {
//eventObj.range
    callCell(eventObj.range.getValue());
}
```

so the `eventObj` gives me current cell value but how to get the past value or in other words the value just before the edit was made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `atEdit` is a function called by on edit installable trigger, then `eventObj` is the edit event object, in such case you could use `eventObj.oldValue`

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events